# How should I manage multiple projects with dependencies with each other using Git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I have multiple projects (A & B) which have sub-directories like shown in the diagram below.

```
A-
  |-AA-
       |-AAA
       |-AAB
  |-AB-
       |-ABA
       |-ABB
B-
  |-BA-
       |-BAA
       |-BAB
  |-BB-
       |-BBA
       |-BBB
```

Each entry is a directory/folder.
For example, to run project in `ABA`, it needs to use some dependencies which are in `AAA`.
And to run the project in `BAA` it uses dependencies present in `AAB`.

The question is, how do I work on `BAA` while retaining the same project structure and only getting contents in folder `AAB`?
So if I'm working on `BAA` the file structure on my local machine should look like this:

```
A-
  |-AA-
       |-AAB
B-
  |-BA-
       |-BAA
```

This way `BAA` knows to look go two directories up and into `A/AA/AAB` and get the dependencies from there.
Would I create repositories for each folder? I have looked into submodules and sparse checkout but still can't seem to figure it out.
[Here's an image of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Urx9.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to "only get contents" from AAB?

Comment: It's just an example, but because I don't want to download all the other files/directories which I don't really need for building `BAA`

Comment: You can also manage and build project in `BAA` and it's dependencies `A/AA/AAB` in another branch.